# How to implement LadderNet (2 U-Nets) in Keras? (With available PyTorch script as reference)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, pytorch, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement the architecture of LadderNet (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07810) in Keras, with only the PyTorch version available as reference. The architecture in the paper is comprised of 2 U-Nets:
[image]

The codes for the PyTorch implementation of LadderNet's architecture (obtained from https://github.com/juntang-zhuang/LadderNet/blob/master/src/LadderNetv65.py) and Keras' implementation of U-Net (obtained from https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py) are respectively:

```
drop = 0.25

def conv3x3(in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
    """3x3 convolution with padding"""
    return nn.Conv2d(in_planes, out_planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride,
                     padding=1, bias=True)


class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    expansion = 1

    def __init__(self, inplanes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        if inplanes!= planes:
            self.conv0 = conv3x3(inplanes,planes)

        self.inplanes = inplanes
        self.planes = planes

        self.conv1 = conv3x3(planes, planes, stride)
        #self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        #self.conv2 = conv3x3(planes, planes)
        #self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.downsample = downsample
        self.stride = stride
        self.drop = nn.Dropout2d(p=drop)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.inplanes != self.planes:
            x = self.conv0(x)
            x = F.relu(x)

        out = self.conv1(x)
        #out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.drop(out)

        out1 = self.conv1(out)
        #out1 = self.relu(out1)

        out2 = out1 + x

        return F.relu(out2)


class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    expansion = 4

    def __init__(self, inplanes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inplanes, planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride,
                               padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes * self.expansion, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes * self.expansion)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.downsample = downsample
        self.stride = stride

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x

        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = self.bn3(out)

        if self.downsample is not None:
            residual = self.downsample(x)

        out += residual
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out

class Initial_LadderBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,planes,layers,kernel=3,block=BasicBlock,inplanes = 3):
        super().__init__()
        self.planes = planes
        self.layers = layers
        self.kernel = kernel

        self.padding = int((kernel-1)/2)
        self.inconv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=inplanes,out_channels=planes,
                                kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1,bias=True)

        # create module list for down branch
        self.down_module_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0,layers):
            self.down_module_list.append(block(planes*(2**i),planes*(2**i)))

        # use strided conv instead of poooling
        self.down_conv_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0,layers):
            self.down_conv_list.append(nn.Conv2d(planes*2**i,planes*2**(i+1),stride=2,kernel_size=kernel,padding=self.padding))

        # create module for bottom block
        self.bottom = block(planes*(2**layers),planes*(2**layers))

        # create module list for up branch
        self.up_conv_list = nn.ModuleList()
        self.up_dense_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0, layers):
            self.up_conv_list.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=planes*2**(layers-i), out_channels=planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1), kernel_size=3,
                                                        stride=2,padding=1,output_padding=1,bias=True))
            self.up_dense_list.append(block(planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1),planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1)))


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.inconv(x)
        out = F.relu(out)

        down_out = []
        # down branch
        for i in range(0,self.layers):
            out = self.down_module_list[i](out)
            down_out.append(out)
            out = self.down_conv_list[i](out)
            out = F.relu(out)

        # bottom branch
        out = self.bottom(out)
        bottom = out

        # up branch
        up_out = []
        up_out.append(bottom)

        for j in range(0,self.layers):
            out = self.up_conv_list[j](out) + down_out[self.layers-j-1]
            #out = F.relu(out)
            out = self.up_dense_list[j](out)
            up_out.append(out)

        return up_out

class LadderBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,planes,layers,kernel=3,block=BasicBlock,inplanes = 3):
        super().__init__()
        self.planes = planes
        self.layers = layers
        self.kernel = kernel

        self.padding = int((kernel-1)/2)
        self.inconv = block(planes,planes)

        # create module list for down branch
        self.down_module_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0,layers):
            self.down_module_list.append(block(planes*(2**i),planes*(2**i)))

        # use strided conv instead of poooling
        self.down_conv_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0,layers):
            self.down_conv_list.append(nn.Conv2d(planes*2**i,planes*2**(i+1),stride=2,kernel_size=kernel,padding=self.padding))

        # create module for bottom block
        self.bottom = block(planes*(2**layers),planes*(2**layers))

        # create module list for up branch
        self.up_conv_list = nn.ModuleList()
        self.up_dense_list = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(0, layers):
            self.up_conv_list.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(planes*2**(layers-i), planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1), kernel_size=3,
                                                        stride=2,padding=1,output_padding=1,bias=True))
            self.up_dense_list.append(block(planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1),planes*2**max(0,layers-i-1)))


    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.inconv(x[-1])

        down_out = []
        # down branch
        for i in range(0,self.layers):
            out = out + x[-i-1]
            out = self.down_module_list[i](out)
            down_out.append(out)

            out = self.down_conv_list[i](out)
            out = F.relu(out)

        # bottom branch
        out = self.bottom(out)
        bottom = out

        # up branch
        up_out = []
        up_out.append(bottom)

        for j in range(0,self.layers):
            out = self.up_conv_list[j](out) + down_out[self.layers-j-1]
            #out = F.relu(out)
            out = self.up_dense_list[j](out)
            up_out.append(out)

        return up_out

class Final_LadderBlock(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,planes,layers,kernel=3,block=BasicBlock,inplanes = 3):
        super().__init__()
        self.block = LadderBlock(planes,layers,kernel=kernel,block=block)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.block(x)
        return out[-1]

class LadderNetv6(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,layers=3,filters=16,num_classes=2,inplanes=3):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial_block = Initial_LadderBlock(planes=filters,layers=layers,inplanes=inplanes)
        #self.middle_block = LadderBlock(planes=filters,layers=layers)
        self.final_block = Final_LadderBlock(planes=filters,layers=layers)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters,out_channels=num_classes,kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.initial_block(x)
        #out = self.middle_block(out)
        out = self.final_block(out)
        out = self.final(out)
        #out = F.relu(out)
        out = F.log_softmax(out,dim=1)
        return out
```

and

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

I'm very new to PyTorch, and I am still familiarizing myself with the transition between Keras and PyTorch, and I'm also hoping that the above can help in this transition of mine.

With regards to the implementation in Keras for LadderNet, if I understood the paper correctly, is it simply just 2 U-Nets superimposed side-by-side (named `LaddderNetKeras`) as follows:

```
def LadderNetKeras(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    # SECOND U-NET
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv10)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)


    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model
```

Thank you and some insights will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation of laddernet in Keras available here : https://github.com/divamgupta/ladder_network_keras/blob/master/ladder_net.py. Consider this as a starting point, I have used at a point this repository successfully.

Comment: Thanks! Let me look this up in the mean time :)

Comment: Gonna mark this as accepted! Thanks again. Just to add, perhaps it will be great if you could add in the code from the link above for future reference, in the event that the link gets removed in the future.